# Determine the tablespace name for a lob

Tags: sql, database, oracle, blobs

I created four tablespaces like this :

```
CREATE TABLESPACE da_ts; 
CREATE TABLESPACE db_ts;
CREATE TABLESPACE bd_bts;
CREATE TABLESPACE be_bts;
```

I created a partitioned table like this

```
create table orders_partitioned(id_dnm number, clob_dnm clob)
  partition by hash(id_dnm)
    (partition p1
       tablespace da_ts lob (clob_dnm)
       store as (tablespace bd_bts),
     partition p2
       tablespace db_ts lob (clob_dnm)
       store as (tablespace be_bts));
```

I am able to insert rows into the partitioned table and also able to retrieve them. How do I find out if the lobs are going to the right tablespaces? I mean, is there a way I can determine all the lobs inserted in the database and what tablespaces they are stored in?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine for a particular row which partition (and thus tablespace) that particular table and lob are stored in?  How to determine which rows are in each partition?  How to see in the data dictionary that different partitions are putting their lobs in different tablespaces?  Or something else?

Comment: Why do you think the rows might not be stored in the tablespaces that you specified in your `create table` statement?

Comment: I am asking "When I insert a row. into what partition does the row go into and what tablespace the row goes into?" . @a_horse_with_no_name I know it might be going to the right tablespace, I want to know if there is a way to find out